# Include works but Join is not working c# linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, webapi

I'm trying to get all the cars with the owners. One owner can have multiple cars and one car can be registered to one owner.

If I type a query like this I get the expected result:

```
public List<Owner> Get()
{
    var ownerWithCars = db.Owner.Include(o => o.Cars).AsNoTracking().ToList();
    return ownerWithCars;

}
```

But this query is not working:

```
public List<Owner> Get()
{
    var cars = from o in db.Owners join c in db.Cars on o.Id equals c.OwnerId into cars
               select new Owner() {Id = o.Id, Address = o.Address, Cars = cars.ToList()};
    return cars;
}
```

If I run the second query I get the following error:

```
"ExceptionMessage": "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
```

I have added the following to my `global.asax`

```
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings
.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters
            .Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Comment: may not be related to the error; assuming Car has primary key Id, shouldn't `o.Id equals c.Id` be `o.Id equals c.OwnerId`

Comment: Oh yes true, I edited my query a few times and the last time I forgot to put c.OwnerId instead of c.Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result set you get with your first query using `Include` can be get using `join` by writing your 2nd query slightly differently. You can try:

```
public List<Owner> Get()
{
    var ownerWithCars = (from o in db.Owners
                join c in db.Cars on o.Id equals c.OwnerId into cars 
                select o).ToList();

    return ownerWithCars ;
}
```

Comment: Did you try the other one? `var ownerWithCars  = (from o in db.Owners 
                         join c in db.Cars on o.Id equals c.OwnerId
                         select o).Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: I first used ```public ICollection<Car> Cars {get; set;}```, then I got ```cars:null```, when I changed it to ```public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars {get; set;}```, I got the results with the query which you mentioned. Can it be the problem that I didnt put virtual to my navigation property?

Comment: My pleasure. Happy to help. Please delete some of non relevant chat so it's clean for future users. I'll add `virtual` part as note to answer.